# Same sentence different vectors with sent2vec vectorizer

Tags: python, scipy, pymongo, word2vec, bert-language-model

Hi im trying some code where i have some sample data stored in mongodb.
Im querying the data appending into list and then i have a sentence which i need to find the vectors and find cosine similarity but the issue is when i calculate vectors for same sentences the vectors are coming up different for the one calculated from the mongo db.

```
from scipy import spatial
from sent2vec.vectorizer import Vectorizer
from pymongo import MongoClient
# Connecting to local mongo
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
database = client['test']
collection = database['test']
cursor = collection.find({})
#empty list to append the data from mongo
info = []
#test data
info1 = ['hello im john',]
info2 = ['hello im john',]
for document in cursor:
    info.append(str(document["title"]))
    # break
print(info) #check the data
print(info1)
vectorizer = Vectorizer()
vectorizer.run(info)
vectors_info = vectorizer.vectors #mongo data vectors
vectorizer = Vectorizer()
vectorizer.run(info1)
vectors_info1 = vectorizer.vectors  #test data vectors

#comparing the vectors
print(vectors_info[0]==vectors_info1[0])

vectorizer = Vectorizer()
vectorizer.run(info2)
vectors_info2 = vectorizer.vectors 
#comparing same text again
print(vectors_info1[0]==vectors_info2[0])
```

The output is as follow

```
 python3 test.py 
['hello im john', 'hello im tez']
['hello im john']
Initializing Bert distilbert-base-uncased
Vectorization done on cpu
Some weights of the model checkpoint at distilbert-base-uncased were not used when initializing DistilBertModel: ['vocab_transform.weight', 'vocab_layer_norm.weight', 'vocab_projector.weight', 'vocab_transform.bias', 'vocab_projector.bias', 'vocab_layer_norm.bias']
- This IS expected if you are initializing DistilBertModel from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForPreTraining model).
- This IS NOT expected if you are initializing DistilBertModel from the checkpoint of a model that you expect to be exactly identical (initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForSequenceClassification model).
Initializing Bert distilbert-base-uncased
Vectorization done on cpu
Some weights of the model checkpoint at distilbert-base-uncased were not used when initializing DistilBertModel: ['vocab_transform.weight', 'vocab_layer_norm.weight', 'vocab_projector.weight', 'vocab_transform.bias', 'vocab_projector.bias', 'vocab_layer_norm.bias']
- This IS expected if you are initializing DistilBertModel from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForPreTraining model).
- This IS NOT expected if you are initializing DistilBertModel from the checkpoint of a model that you expect to be exactly identical (initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForSequenceClassification model).
[False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False]
Initializing Bert distilbert-base-uncased
Vectorization done on cpu
Some weights of the model checkpoint at distilbert-base-uncased were not used when initializing DistilBertModel: ['vocab_transform.weight', 'vocab_layer_norm.weight', 'vocab_projector.weight', 'vocab_transform.bias', 'vocab_projector.bias', 'vocab_layer_norm.bias']
- This IS expected if you are initializing DistilBertModel from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForPreTraining model).
- This IS NOT expected if you are initializing DistilBertModel from the checkpoint of a model that you expect to be exactly identical (initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForSequenceClassification model).
[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
```

for print(vectors_info[0]==vectors_info1[0]) all are false where as for print(vectors_info1[0]==vectors_info2[0]) its true.

tried to check if both the strings are same with  info[0]==info[1] it returns true.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `vectors_info` should be the results of running the `Vectorizer` on a list with 2 string items:

```
['hello im john', 'hello im tez']
```

It appears that `vectors_info1` and `vectors_info2` should be the results of running the `Vectorizer` on a list with 1 string item:

```
['hello im john']
```

Thus I'd expect to get one vector reported back from `Vectorizer` for the 1st 2-item list, and some *other* vector for the two times `Vectorizer` is asked about the 2nd 1-item list.

That seems to be exactly what your output shows. To get the same vector back, you would need to pass the same input.

(You may also want to double-check whether `sent2vec.Vectorizer` expects a string, or a list-of-words, or something else – and that you are passing it the form it needs.)